# Value of child object in two way binded value is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I use Nuxt, just to be clear upfront.

The structure of my project is:

Default Layout -> Servicebar (this is where I want to get the value of service.btnStatus.show)
Index (app) -> Several components that manipulate its parent data (service) object

The 'service' object is a part of my Vue data object in index.js:

```
data () {
  return {
    service: {
      title: '',
      id: -1,
      btnNew: false,
      btnEdit: false,
      btnSave: false,
      btnCancel: false,
      btnStatus: {
        show: false,
        value: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a 'ServiceBar' component which is set in the default layout. This component contains a 'CheckboxToggle' child component which I want to show or hide using v-if="service.btnStatus.show".

In the 'ServiceBar' component 'service' is a computed prop.

When I try to get the value of a child of 'service', for instance 'title', I have no problem, however when I try to get the value of a grand child, for instance 'show', I get undefined.

```
v-if="service.btnStatus.show"
```

in a grand child object is undefined.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: please provide the structure of your components

Comment: Please see 'The structure of my project is' in question.

Comment: There's not enough info to reproduce the problem. Please provide a reproducible example in Codesandbox.